# Use Regular Expression to extract text between two characters

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a list of names in the following format:

```
"Abbing, Mr. Anthony"
"Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward"
"Abbott, Mrs. Stanton (Rosa Hunt)"
```

And I want to extract the title (i.e. "Mr", "Mrs"). It is always between the comma and the dot.

I'm only new to regular expressions, this is what i'm trying to use but i'm not getting the correct answer.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name from ',..')
```

I get ", M" as an answer.

I assume this is something very simple to fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
substring(name from '(, (Mr)(s){0,1}\.)')
```

will extract `, Mr.` or `, Mrs.`. Note the parentheses around the whole expression. `substring( ... from ..)` will return the match from the first group in the regex. As I have used `(Mr)` and `(s)` to match the titles, I have to put everything between parentheses to make `substring()` return the whole pattern

to get rid of the leading `', '` you can use `trim()`

```
trim(substring(name from '(, (Mr)(s){0,1}\.)'), ', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name from ',\s([^\.]+)\.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position` and `substring` function to do this:

```
SELECT samplename
    ,trim(substring(samplename, position(',' IN samplename) + 1
          , position('.' IN samplename) - position(',' IN samplename))) AS initials
FROM test
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a226a/14/0)